# Setting Cron Job For every five minutes to clean up log tables will slow down the site?

Tags: cron, log-cleaning

I Have setup cron on my sites and it seems it was working fine I have scheduled them to clear the log tables for every 5 minutes. do this will down the performance of the site anymore? If so Do I need to extend the time of cron or any other things I have to follow ?

*From OP comment:* "My sort of problem is Log table dramatically increased so that I have setup the cron to clear it out, and Now Hosting have reported that sites performance frequently slows down with hits"

Comment: Cleaning the log table in every 5 min is not a good practice and may have performance related problems. You should do it in the range 30 days to 180 days.

Comment: So This is causing the problem ?

Comment: Can you specify the problem ?

Comment: My sort of problem is Log table dramatically increased so that I have setup the cron to clear it out, and Now Hosting have reported that sites performance frequently slows down with hits

Comment: They also came up with some other tables like Catalog_Search_results are running with slow queries

Comment: Can you specify which log table size is increasing abnormally.

Comment: There may be spam bots hiting your search

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372402/malicious-search-attempts-showing-in-popular-search-terms-in-magento read this link for more info

Comment: Log_url, visitor  and their info tables were increasing,... However these things were normal when cron runs

Comment: This may be a case of spamming.

Comment: The Above link have answer to resolve this issue ?

Comment: yes, you should definitely do something to prevent spam in your site.

Comment: Hi My Log_visitor_info Table contains agent:YandexBot

Comment: disallow it in your robot.txt file

Comment: Hi I have disallowed it via Robot.txt and cleared out log tables at once I found that However this bot stuff again loaded into log tables after an hour...

Comment: contact your hosting provider, they may send you up any solution. Robot.txt should work, may be you are doing something wrong. folow this link for detailed info http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/restricting-bots/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-your-website

Answer (score 1):

While cleaning your log tables periodically is ok, every 5 minutes is over kill.

If your job does take more than 5 minutes to run will will also run into the possibility of two of the same jobs running at the same time. This will further degrade your performance.

You should start by cleaning every night (Say at 2am) this will mitigate any performance issues you would have for running the job.

You can run a simple script on your database to find your big tables.

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = 'database'
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

From this you can access how big your log tables are getting and how often you need to clean them.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me the promotion, but instead of wiping out logs after they have filled up, it might be even smarter to prevent those logs from taking place first of all. I have shared a module for this on GitHub and it should do the job: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_DisableLog2